# Shuffling and combining two vectors

Tags: r

I have two vectors (they can be different length, can contain `NA`'s)

```
chars <- letters[1:3]
nums <- 1:5
```

I want to shuffle them so that I have a single vector: `chars[1], nums[1], chars[2], nums[2], ..., chars[n], nums[n]`. My current approach is the following

```
as.vector(vapply(1:5, function(i) c(chars[i], nums[i]), character(2)))
```

Is there a better way to do this? I don't like about my solution the transformation vector -> matrix -> vector. Using a for-loop is an obvious alternative but I am looking for better ones if possible.

Comment: What do want to achieve?  Do you want a single vector, or the original vectors shuffled?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen A single vector, like in the example.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Why did you remove your answer. Simply need some edit I guess.